# Object Reference not set to instance of object

Tags: c#

```
string[][] myArray = new[size][];
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
myArray[i][0] = newValue.toString();
}
```

While assigning the values i get an error
I get the `Object Reference not set to instance of object` exception. Please help

Answer (score 10):

You have created a *jagged* array of strings. The outermost array has been initialized to `size` elements, but that means there are `size` spaces each for a `string[]`, each of which is currently `null`. You need to create the *inner* arrays, or create a *rectangular* array.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the poor code, it should be something like this:

```
  string[][] myArray = new string[size][];
  for (int j = 0; j < myArray.Length; j++) {
    myArray[j] = new string[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray[j].Length; i++) {
      myArray[j][i] = newValue.ToString();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I was trying to create an array like myArray[0][1] = Value ; I was trying to store the value on 1 index of 0 so that 0 index store 4 differnt values my concept was to do it like php  <?php $array = array(); $array[0][1] = newvalue 1; $array[0][1] = newvalue2; ?>  Its hard for me to adopt the syntaxes in C# as I was a php developer so I hope you understand my poor line of codes in C# but I am improvig. please help thanx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        int dim1 = 2;
        int dim2 = 1;

        string[,] iii = new string[dim1, dim2];         

        for (int i = 0; i < iii.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            iii[i, 0] = "myValue";
        }
```